# What is a source table, and a target table?

Tags: terminology

I've seen alot of talk about source tables, and target tables on the internet, but no definitions of what these things are...from what I can infer it seems to mean something about copying data from an old table with an old schema into a new table with a new schema...is this what it means?

Comment: It can mean that or any thing related, it can mean transferring data from oracle to sql server, or from production systems to your data warehouse. it can many all of that, the source table is the table which you will import your data from and the destination is the final location that your data will go to. read about Extract, transform and load (ETL)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially the source table is the place where the data is coming from and the target table is the place where the data is going to or the table that an action is taking place on. They do not have to be in different schema's or have a different structure to each other and in fact they could actually be the same table.